# Getting the download URL of an image in Firebase Storage, using `ref()`

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm uploading some images to Firebase Storage using the Javascript API. The resulting object I get looks like this:

```
{
  bucket: 'my-bucket',
  contentType: 'image/jpeg',
  ...
  id: 'my-bucket/path/to/image.jpeg',
  mediaLink: "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/my-bucket/o/path%2Fto%2Fimage.jpeg?generation=123456789&alt=media",
  name: 'path/to/image.jpeg',
  selfLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my-bucket/o/path%2Fto%2Fimage.jpeg',
  ...
}
```

As you can see, I get an `id`, a `name` and two links, which are all somehow related. Some of them have the path encoded, some are relative, some are absolute.

Now I want to download it, using the Javascript API, with a logged-in user. This works great:

```
let urlPromise = firebase.storage()
    .refFromURL("gs://my-bucket/path/to/image.jpeg")
    .getDownloadUrl();
```

However, I cannot get it to work with the `ref()` API:

```
let urlPromise = firebase.storage()
    .ref("path/to/image.jpeg")
    .getDownloadUrl();
```

Instead of `path/to/image.jpeg` (the `name`), I also tried `id`, `mediaLink` and `selfLink`, but I always get a `FirebaseStorageError` (404).

What exact parameter is expected in the `.ref()` method?

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Storage#ref) are not specific either.

**Edit:** Here's an actual screenshot of how the file appears in the Firebase console:

[image]

If I pass the `Name` property (`1997_Ford_Falcon_(EL)_GLi_sedan_(17670566466).jpg_320px-1997_Ford_Falcon_(EL.jpg`) to `ref()`, I get a 404. If I use the `gs://my-bucket/...` path, it says that `ref()` cannot take a URL.

**Edit 2:** I inspected the exact URLs which are generated by the two methods. This is the URL I get from `ref()`:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-bucket.appspot.com/
o/upload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2F0%2F00%2F1997_Ford_Falcon_(EL)_GLi_
sedan_(17670566466).jpg_320px-1997_Ford_Falcon_(EL.jpg
```

This is the working URL from `refFromURL()`:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-bucket/
o/upload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2F0%2F00%2F1997_Ford_Falcon_(EL)_GLi_
sedan_(17670566466).jpg_320px-1997_Ford_Falcon_(EL.jpg
```

As you can see, the `ref()` method adds a `.appspot.com` to the bucket name. This seems to cause the problem.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the file in the storage bucket using the Firebase console?  The path should be exactly what you see on the screen, and it will work with the ref() method.

Comment: @DougStevenson good to know, thanks. Gonna try again.

Comment: @DougStevenson tried that, see my edit. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the full path of the file.  What you're passing right now:

> 1997_Ford_Falcon_(EL)_GLi_sedan_(17670566466).jpg_320px-1997_Ford_Falcon_(EL.jpg

Is missing the prefix of the path where it's located, which you can see from the screenshot:

> upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/1997_Ford_Falcon_(EL)_GLi_sedan_(17670566466).jpg_320px-1997_Ford_Falcon_(EL.jpg

Do not pass the "gs" or the name of the bucket.  It's just the path to the object within the bucket.

Comment: Unfortunately, I also get 404's with the full path. However, now I have some more information about the problem, see my edit.